# Swift Http body convert

Tags: swift

I have Http body as below

```
Subject=Example
[MSISDN] 
List=+44777123123,+44777123124,+44777123125 
[MESSAGE]
Text=A SAMPLE SMS to three mobile phones. 
[SETUP]
MobileNotification=YES
[END]
```

I want to post it server but i can't figure out how i translate body correctly. I am using Alamofire library. I tried

```
let parameters:[String:AnyObject] = [
        "Subject"   : "Example",
        "MSISDN"    : [
            "List" :["+905555555555"]
        ],
        "MESSAGE"   : [
            "Text" : "Test text bla bla bla"
        ],
        "SETUP"     : [
            "MobileNotification": "YES",
            "OriginatorPort"    : "1581"
        ]
    ]
```

and

```
let parameters:[String:AnyObject] = [
        "Subject"   : "Example",
        "List"      :["+905555555555"],
        "Text"      : "Test text bla bla bla",
        "MobileNotification" : "YES"
    ]
```

but i got 400 bad request.

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, URL, headers: headers, parameters: parameters)
            .responseString{ response  in
                print(response.debugDescription)
                print(response.response?.statusCode)
                print(response.request?.allHTTPHeaderFields)
                switch response.result {
                case .Success:
                    print(response.request?.HTTPBody)
                case .Failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
let parameters:[String:AnyObject] = [
    "Subject"   : "Example",
    "MSISDN"    :["+44777123123","+44777123124","+44777123125"],
    "MESSAGE"   : "A SAMPLE SMS to three mobile phones.",
    "MobileNotification" : "YES"
]
```

Comment: 6017 Bad format or missing mandatory value for field Text in section MESSAGE.

Comment: I think its SAP web service and you have to send the request in XML format!

Comment: Yes it is SAP servis but it is  HTTP Interface

Comment: https://www.nova.is/aspnetweb/services/SupportService.asmx?op=sendSMS , explain more